# Loopback Android SDK - Add related model instance

Tags: android, model, loopbackjs, has-many, strongloop

How can I add an instance of a related model through the Loopback Android SDK?

Example: Model Question, hasMany Model Answers. I only want to expose Model Question through the REST API. So to add an Answer to a Question using the explorer, I use POST /Questions/{id}/answers.

But how can I achieve the same using the Android SDK?

Comment: I think this [issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sdk-android/issues/63) is related, and there hasn't been any update on it since January 2015, so I assume there is (still) no way to do this?